# Replace outliers in a mixed dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, outliers

I have a mixed dataframe with both str, int and float types. I have some outliers in the floats columns and tried to replace them to NaN using

```
df.mask(df.sub(df.mean()).div(df.std()).abs().gt(2))
```

I've also tried with numpy's

```
v = df.values
mask = np.abs((v - v.mean(0)) / v.std(0)) > 2
pd.DataFrame(np.where(mask, np.nan, v), df.index, df.columns)`
```

But for both I'm getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'` and `TypeError: must be str, not float`

I've also tried to apply this only for the column with the outliers but it's not modifying anything

This is what the df looks like

```
    dateRep     cases   deaths  countriesAndTerritories     countryterritoryCode    popData2018 
0   03/05/2020  134.0   4.0     Afghanistan     AFG     37172386.0
1   02/05/2020  164.0   4.0     Afghanistan     AFG     37172386.0
2   01/05/2020  222.0   NaN     Afghanistan     AFG     37172386.0
3   30/04/2020  122.0   0.0     Afghanistan     AFG     37172386.0
4   29/04/2020  124.0   3.0     Afghanistan     AFG     37172386.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this (this is to change the "cases" column):

```
df.loc[abs(df.cases - df.cases.mean())/df.cases.std() > 1, "cases"] = None
```

However, note that here I have used a Z value of 1 for the "Cases" column, since the largest Z value is 1.63 (instance with index = 2). You are trying to modify values with Z values greater than 2, none of these instances have a Z value greater than 2.

Hope this helps!